# What is the volume of ice that has melted (in cubic kilometers)?

Tags: geometry, volume

Since 1960, sea level has risen 30 mm due to added water from melting glaciers. If the ocean area is 361 million square kilometers, what is the volume of ice that has melted (in cubic kilometers)?

Comment: Difficult to say. A good amount of the sea level rise is from thermal expansion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then the area added is base times height, or, in this case, area of the ocean, or $361,000,000\cdot(1000\  \text{meters})^2$, times the height added ($30\cdot 10^{-3}$ meters).

Comment: If I did the math correctly, the volume of ice that has melted is 10,830,000,000,000 cubic kilometers. Correct?

Comment: That would be in meters. Then divide by $(1000\ \text{meters})^3$ to get 10830 cubic kilometers.

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=30mm+times+361+million+square+km